# Getting a variable not defined error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting an error saying that x is not defined. I am simply trying to conduct a check that if a string contains all the characters that are in a set, it returns true. But if it doesn't contain one or more characters in the set it returns false. Is this a correct way to approach this?

```
wanted_chars=set('e_[/H]')
titles=['[Fe/H]','e_[Fe/H]']

for i in range(len(titles)):
if x in wanted_chars and x in titles[i]:
     print(str(titles[i])+": This contains the wanted letters!")
else:
     print(str(titles[i])+": This does not contain the wanted letters!")
```

So, just to clarify, the string in titles can contain more characters than the set, but has to contain all the characters that exist in the set. So titles[0] should satisfy this but titles[1] will not. I understand that x is not necessarily defined, but I am under the impression that x is being assigned to a character in the set then checked against all the characters in the string, and iterated for each character in the set.  Sorry if this seems like a silly question, but I have thoroughly searched the internet and tried other methods to no avail.  I want to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can't see where x is defined in you're code

Comment: I can't see where _any_ of the variables referenced in your code are defined. Please note that we ask questions to include a [mcve] that is self-contained and can be run to reproduce your issue

Comment: As @MadyDaby says, x isn't defined in your code. Your question asks, in essence, why a similar line of code works. One possibility is that all prior if statements are passed over, so you don't see the error until your commented line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to indent the for loop first after the first if statement may be it will solve the problem

Comment: Certainly the empty `if` statement at the top of the code sample is a problem - one that some interpreters would choke on - but it's very unclear whether that is **the** problem raised here. We need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you haven't defined the variable x in your code.
The reason it occurs where you have signaled is because it is bypassing the previous if statements, because the conditions of those ifs are not true.